# Spark job did not find table in Hive database

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have a table in default database of Hive, and can sucessfully get records from that table in command line:

```
>hive: select * from my_table;
```

But when I create a job in Spark to run, it just throwns me exception like this:

```
INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=my_table
16/01/04 03:41:42 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=etl     ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=my_table
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table my_table;
```

Here is the code of that job:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("PhucdullApp");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc.sc());
        DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql("select * from my_table");
        df.show();
        sc.close();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*(Assuming that you are using default Derby database which is configured in hive-default.xml file)*. Ensure that you have followed the following steps: -

1. Copy hive-default.xml from **$HIVE_HOME/conf/** to **$SPARK_HOME/conf/** directory.
2. locate your "metastore_db" directory and submit your Spark Job from the same directory using spark-submit command.

Comment: Great job, it works like a charm by just following your first step. But can you explain me why we should copy hive-default.xml to $SPARK_HOME/conf? There is no one in Apache guideline tell me to do that. Please up +1 for me.

Comment: You are executing Hive queries by leveraging Spark-SQL extension and it requires the access to hive-site.xml or hive-default.xml file. Apache docs talks about copying the Hive-site.xml file. Refer here - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html. Please do remember to Vote and mark he answer as correct if it helped you.